# Writing file names generated on a particular date into a text file in Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How do I write filenames from a particular directory that are generated on a particular date to a text file? For eg.

Suppose in the directory "home/temp" I have the files

```
temp1.txt  12-NOV-2020
temp2.txt  12-NOV-2020
temp3.txt  14-NOV-2020
```

I want to have a text file, say "filenames.txt" which will have the filenames of all the files generated on 12-NOV-2020.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO

Comment: Are those dates part of the file name?

Comment: Try something like `find home/temp -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mtime 14`. You might have to modify the number `14`  depending on the day when you execute the command compared to the day when the files have been modified. See the documentation of the `find` command: [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: By 'generated', do you mean 'last modified on'?  Most file systems don't record the 'birth date' when a file was first created (the Mac file system is one exception that does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, few are -

### Using the date given by `ls -l` output

```sh
$ ls -l  | grep "Nov 26" | awk '{print $9}'
temp1.txt
temp2.txt
temp3.txt
$
```

.. and redirect the output of above to `filename.txt` to have these in a file.

```sh
$ ls -l  | grep "Nov 26" | awk '{print $9}' > filename.txt
$
```

### Using various dates given by `stat`

Assuming you're interested in the `last data modification date` you can use the format string `%y`, `%n` just adds the name of the file below for `awk` to be able to fetch it.

refer: `man stat`, `man awk` if you're not already aware of these utilities.

```sh
$ stat -c %n' '%y *.txt | awk '/2020-11-26/{print $1}'
temp1.txt
temp2.txt
temp3.txt
$
```

Comment: `find` can test the modification time using `-mtime` and maybe `-daystart`. You don't need `find` and `xargs` to pass file names specified as `*.txt` to `stat`. The wildcard gets expanded by the shell before executing `find`. Simply use `*.txt` directly as an argument for `stat` like `stat -c %n' '%y *.txt`

Comment: Ah yes! I have a habit of using `fd`/`find` and piping it to others especially when dealing with a a lot of files which are in recursive directories. For the use case here, none of it is required. I have edited my answer to remove `find` and `xargs`. Thanks @Bodo!